# Cannot 'like' canvas app via Facebook URL, only via source URL

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-canvas

Fairly simple question, but can't seem to find any answers.

Within a canvas app, I want users to be able to like a page that links directly to the app (http://apps.facebook.com/crunchd/profile/545998365), rather than to the source URL (http://facebook.crunchd.com/profile/545998365).

The first link does not work, with the like box appearing and then disappearing quickly afterwards, while the second works fine. It's not styling, as it's being tested with http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

All the og tags are set up correctly, as tested with the linter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is your dev environment on a localhost or is it hosted? are you getting any consol or network errors in firebug/inspector?

Comment: All on a live environment (links above are the links I'm using). Getting 'Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL' on both the working link and broken link, so doubt it's related.

Comment: And what does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say? is it able to reach your metadata or is your canvas app trying to redirect, etc?

Comment: Checked the debug as well, all fine on the metadata front. Facebook takes the metadata from the frame the canvas app is showed in, so these are correct:
http://bitly.com/Tw26Fi
http://bit.ly/UjTSwE